# what does "[," mean in the syntax for describing input parameters format?

Tags: syntax, input-parameters

This is a rookie question but I couldn't find the name / keyword for this kind of syntax that is widely used in describing input parameters formats. For example:

```
Request method aliases
For convenience aliases have been provided for all supported request methods.

axios.request(config)
axios.get(url[, config])
axios.delete(url[, config])
axios.head(url[, config])
axios.options(url[, config])
axios.post(url[, data[, config]])
axios.put(url[, data[, config]])
axios.patch(url[, data[, config]])
```

The syntax `url[, config]` or `url[, data[, config]]` just looks really strange and is not self explanatory. What is the name for this kind of syntax?

I've seen them widely used but not sure how to read them.  I just need someone to point a direction and tell a keyword / name or two about this syntax.

Comment: It's an optional parameter, which you can but not need to provide. If you don't provide it, some default value (typically described in the docs as well) is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself here in case anyone had the same confusion:

whatever goes in `[]` is optional. For example:

The expression of `axios.get(url[, config])` means that:

1. `axios.get(url)` is acceptable, and
2. `axios.get(url, config)` is also acceptable.